# SQL Server 2012 Reporting Service Authentication Required

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

Our team has created an ASP website which uses reportviewer control for rendering reports from report server.

On the main report, we have used Go to URL to show subreport in new window(pop up).  I have hosted this website  on IIS server.

When we try to access main report (i.e. Home.aspx), we are getting content of main report from reporting server and it's not asking me for credentials.

But when we click on link for subreport. it is asking for credentials for pop up window. I am not getting point that why it's asking credentials for only pop-up and not for main report. If my SSRS is not properly configured, then it should ask credentials for main report as well but it prompt for only pop-up.

We are using SSRS 2008. SSRS and IIS both are on same machine.  We have used javascript function for Go to URL  expression.

Following are screenshots for both scenario.

Main Report - Links to subreport which is open in new pop up window (No credentials asked here)

[image]

Subreport Pop up windows (Prompt for  credentials)

[image]

Comment: are you using the same datasource on both report's datasets?

Comment: just for the sake of testing, try to set the sub report to run inside the main report

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We couldn't use Kerberos in the end as it we were unable to make such changes to our server. I've no doubt it would work though, as we've since removed authentication, which removed the logon issue, so we can trial the reporting on our network.

Answer (score 1):

now that I gave a longer thought, "Go to URL" is a report action, so you are not exactly using a "subreport". A subreport is a component that opens a report inside another report.

The action that is more proximate of what you need would be a drill through report, but this will open the new report on the same context of the actual report.

Regarding the credentials, I think that it is asking because since you are new hop.

Follow my line of thought (and this is just a guess so forgive me if Im saying something absurd), when you call report1, the connection goes report1 -> data source (1hop, fine). When you call report2 from report1, report1 sends the credentials to report2 (1 hop) and report2 tries to connect to the data source (second hop), and AD only supports one hop, that's why I think it is requesting for credentials.

Maybe if you configure [kerberos](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2008/06/13/understanding-kerberos-double-hop.aspx) authentication, it may work...

Comment: Thanks @Diego, we'll give it a go and report back :)

Comment: We couldn't use Kerberos in the end as it we were unable to make such changes to our server! I've no doubt it would work though, as we've since removed authentication, which removed the logon issue, so we can trial the reporting on our network. Thanks for all your help!